# ESlint error when using lodash forEach in jsx

Tags: javascript, jsx, eslint

I have a code:

```
  renderList = () => {
    const result = this.props.searchResult;
    const liArray = [];
    forEach({ a: 1, b: 2 }, (value, key) => {
      liArray.push(<li>hello</li>);
    });
    return (
      <ul className="text-muted m-0 p-0">{liArray}</ul>
    );
  }
```

The eslint is giving error :

> [eslint] Irregular whitespace not allowed. (no-irregular-whitespace).

This error is inside forEach loop. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have copy/pasted some invalid whitespace characters. Just delete the whitespace and type it out by hand.